# Java syntax explained

Tags: java, gwt, syntax

Hey all I'm trying to understand a bit of code in the GWT showcase, and I'm not sure what the following code does. Can someone explain it, and more importantly, explain why the syntax works the way it does? I haven't seen anything like it and I don't know why/how it works. Thanks!

```
public int compareTo(ContactInfo o) {
  return (o == null || o.firstName == null) ? -1 : -o.firstName.compareTo(firstName);
}
```

Comment: This is the inline if statement: "?:".  Just like an actual if-then-else, it has a condition, a true-value and a false-value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means:
If the condition is true, `return -1`, otherwise `return -o.firstName.compareTo(firstName);`

Its a shortcut syntax for `if-then-else`.

After the `?` is what to do if condition is true

After the `:` is what to do if the condition is false

Comment: "Its a shortcut syntax for if then else." It's actually more as it can go inline with parts of expressions.

Comment: `Another conditional operator is ?:, which can be thought of as shorthand for an if-then-else statement ` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: Thanks everyone, explained very well, got it!

Answer (score 0):

if o or o.firstName is null then returns -1;
otherwise returns negative value of o.firstName compared to firstName.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it is the '?' and ':' that confuses you. It is simply a shorthand notation for an if statement like so: `expression ? then-value : else-value`

So in your case it could be written like

```
public int compareTo(ContactInfo o) {
  if (o == null || o.firstName == null)
  then return -1;
  else return -o.firstName.compareTo(firstName);
}
```

(And of course the else can (and should) be omitted)

Answer (score 0):

That is called the ternary operator.

```
boolean value = (condition) ? true : false;
```

This blog post explains what it is and how to use it well.

http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Answer (score 0):

This method is from Comparable interface, in this case specific to ContactInfo. The definition of ContactInfo should be something like this

```
public class ContactInfo  implements Comparable<ContactInfo >{
    ...
}
```

The sentence :

```
contact.compareTo(otherContact);
```

Must return -1 if `contact` is less than `otherContact` (if `firstName` of `contact` is alphabetical  less than `firstName` of `otherContact`), 0 if `contact` is equals to `otherContact`, and and 1 if great than.